# ContextMenu.ItemSource binding issue

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a static resource defined as follows:

```
    <ContextMenu x:Key="TestContextMenu" DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}">
        <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut"/>
        <!--<ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
            <CompositeCollection>
                <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut"/>
            </CompositeCollection>
        </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>-->
    </ContextMenu>
```

My application works fine like this. However, I want to be able to add extra items to the context menu. So instead of adding menu items I want to use a CompositeCollection and then I run into binding issues. I minimized the problem and ended up with this. When I comment the MenuItem and uncomment the `ContextMenu.ItemSource` I get this error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'HorizontalContentAlignment' (type 'HorizontalAlignment')

If the datacontext is correct in the first situation why is it not correct anymore in the second situation?

Edit: I don't want to add items to the contextmenu dynamically. I want to use this contextmenu as kind of a 'base context menu' providing cut/copy and paste from a composite collection resource. In some places I want more than just these three and there I could use a custom context menu that use that same collection combined with those extra items. Just to clarify this is the xaml I have in mind, but I cut the problem down to the simpler piece above.

```
    <CompositeCollection x:Key="TreeViewItemContextMenuItems">
        <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" CommandTarget="{Binding}"/>
        <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
        <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
        <Separator/>
        <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Delete" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
    </CompositeCollection>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="TreeViewItemContextMenu" DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}">
        <ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
            <CompositeCollection>
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{StaticResource TreeViewItemContextMenuItems}" />
            </CompositeCollection>
        </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
    </ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to dynamically populate `ContextMenu` the better solution is do to as follows:

```
<ContextMenu 
    x:Key="TestContextMenu"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">        
</ContextMenu>
```

I removed `DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget...}}"` and added this `ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"`. `MenuItems` is a property of an object used as a data context.  Here is an example of usage:

```
<Window>
    ...
    <ItemsControl ContextMenu="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TestContextMenu}">
        ...
    </ItemsControl>
</Window
```

In this case the context menu will inherit a data context from `ItemsControl` which in turn will inherit a data context from `Window`.

If you don't want to remove `DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget...}}"` then use the following code:

```
<ContextMenu 
    x:Key="TestContextMenu"
    DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.MenuItems}">        
</ContextMenu>
```

**EDIT:**

You receive these errors because `MenuItem` controls by default try to bind some of their properties (`HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment`) to `ItemsControl` using `RelativeSource`. The problem is that their are embeded inside `CompositeCollection` which doesn't support this kind of binding - see [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b15cbd9d-95aa-47c6-8068-7ae9f7dca88a/collectioncontainer-does-not-support-relativesource?forum=wpf) article.

The problem will occure even if you override this binding in your XAML in this way:

```
<MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" CommandTarget="{Binding}"
     HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
```

Probably there is some workaround of this problem but personally I'll ignore these errors. They don't spoil anything in your application, don't they?

Comment: It's not that I want to populate the context menu dynamically. I edited the question to make this clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After some further searching: [workaround](http://weblogs.asp.net/akjoshi/resolving-un-harmful-binding-errors-in-wpf)